# php return "plain text string" from concatenated value based variable for sql database use

Tags: php, sql, return, concatenation

hello guys i need help returning the "plain string text" from this concatenated value variable that is comprised of other multiple variables with string values.

there is a snippet of the code below and how im trying to get it to work.
i am doing it this way for the variable $sql because the search feature on project im working on needs to be dynamic and i have procedural lines of code in place to dynamically edit each of the variables to the right of the $sql variable. i know they work because i can echo the $sql variable and it changes inthe correct fashion

but the problem is 
if i try to pass the $sql variable to the mysqli_query($conn, $sql) the way i have it in first form wont work.

```
$sql = $qrySELECT_FROM.$qryWHERE.$Code.$qryAND.$Cardtype.$qryAND.$Issuer.$qryAND.$State.$qryEND;
```

i need $sql 
to be returned in plain text string form like the one below to be used as my sql statement for the database in the mysqli_query() function.

```
$sqlwayineed = "SELECT * FROM Stuff WHERE code =""; AND cardtype ="" AND issuer ="" AND state ="";
```

can anyone show me the way?

here is fullblown code example to show what im doing and my procedurals
https://eval.in/663376

Comment: Just take your second example and put your variables inside the double quotes for each condition. Note that this code would be potentially vulnerable to SQL injection and you should use parameterized queries instead

Comment: the variables are from hardcoded html select lists so no input fields are available for sql injection

Comment: Famous last words :) Just make sure you [escape them](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Comment: lol i need ur help rob...is what i said false? cause im just learning all this stuff and any knowledge you give me will be soaked up

Comment: Your expected result string does not look like valid SQL, particularly the use of double quotes and semicolons.

Beyond that you should follow simple troubleshooting like breaking down your sql string to the smallest possible portion and working up from there instead of trying to do it all at once and echo-ing the string to see what exactly is being sent to the database and possibly testing it directly on the database.

Even beyond that make sure that however you generate the sub-strings you guard against SQL injection and other invalid input.

Comment: @GullyBoy here's an example:  https://eval.in/663371

Comment: @Sunknight0 im using MYSQL and mirian database and the echo'ed string is in fact working on the database if i copy and paste it in...the problem is removing the human manual copy and paste part and getting PHP to somehow extract that plain string for me and put it in place

Comment: i added eval so u guys can see full code

Comment: if you echo `$sql` and then when pasting directly to your database you get valid results then the problem is not in the formation of the `$sql` variable.

Comment: There's no way it could work correctly with `;`  before `AND`. That character separates multiple queries.

Comment: there is nowhere a ; comes before an AND in my code..i can add the html part also so u can actually see the output is legit sql query if needed @Barmar

Comment: @GullyBoy It's in `$sqlwayineed`.

Comment: $sqlwayineed isnt a actual variable its there to show how i need it outputed or returned for my sql use check the evail.in in post to see my code